# How to create a Loader durning dataTable export

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, datatable

I am try to a hide div with `dataTable` and show div with `loader` durning export data from dataTable by using one of buttons, but nothing happend.

DataTableButtons version 1.6.2 

My code:


HMTL:

```
<div class="loader-div">
// HERE is loader instance
</div>
<div class="table_div">
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">

   </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'pdf'
        ]
}),
$loaderDiv = $('.loader-div'),
$tableDiv = $('.table_div');

dataTable.on('buttons-processing', function (e, indicator) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (indicator) { 
                    $tableDiv.css('display', 'none', 'important');             
                    $loaderDiv.css('display', 'block', 'important');     
                } else {       
                    $loaderDiv.css('display', 'none', 'important');
                    $tableDiv.css('display', 'block', 'important');
                }
            }, 50);
        })
```

Any suggestion or solutions to issue?

Comment: You are doing same thing in indicator and not indicator...

Comment: Thanks @Dani for comment , but look if indicatior is true I hide table and show loader else  I hide loader and show table .

Comment: Yeah, line in reverse order, sorry xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to create custom button and call selected export type.

Here is code:

```
$('#example').dataTable(function() {
 // another dataTable options
 buttons: [
            {
                text: 'TESt',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    let that = this;
                    $tableDiv.css('display', 'none', 'important');
                    $loaderDiv.css('display', 'block', 'important');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action.call(that, e, dt, node, config);

                        $loaderDiv.css('display', 'none', 'important');
                        $tableDiv.css('display', 'block', 'important');
                    }, 50);
                }
            }
        ]
})
```